# Java Store UUID

Tags: java, registry, guid, uuid, hardware-id

I have a question about storing a UUID. I would like to use Java to generate a UUID and save it so that I can retrieve it the next time the application runs.

In a .NET application I built, I'm doing something similar to this. I'm using the Windows Registry to store the UUID and all other settings. However, this Java application is supposed to be cross-platform compatible. This presents the problem. Obviously on other operating systems I won't have the Windows Registry for such a task, so how would I go about this?

I have one solution for this problem, but I'd like something slightly more sophisticated. My current solution is storing a text file (named something like `unique.txt`) in the application's directory and then reading it at runtime.

Here are my grievances about that solution:

- If the user moves the application to a new directory, the program has to generate a new UUID and settings file.
- I don't like the fact that the user can see the settings file sitting in their directory.

Here are the conditions I'd like a solution to satisfy:

- The solution should be able to store a UUID value (and possibly other variables) in such a way that they can be retrieved and modified at runtime.
- If the application is deleted and then re-downloaded, the values of the previous installation should still be retrievable.
- The file used to store the values should not appear in the directory of the application (no sense cluttering up the users directory with a settings file).
- If the user moves the application to a different directory, the application should still be able to retrieve the previous settings file. The settings should not be dependent on the directory.

I have thought about storing the settings file in the root directory (`/` on unix and `C:\` on Windows); however, in my experience, writing to the root directory typically requires elevated permissions. I also feel like the root directory is not the most appropriate location for this.

If Java has a built in method for doing something like this, I would greatly appreciate someone pointing me in the direction of it. Otherwise, if someone could provide some guidance, that would also be great.

I apologize if this question is a duplicate. I've searched for something like this, but I haven't found an answer. If anything about the question is unclear, please add a comment and I'll try to revise the question to clarify.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Preferences API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/overview.html) should provide what you need. If you want common settings for the entire system, check out [`systemNodeForPackage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html#systemNodeForPackage-java.lang.Class-). Something like this (not tested):

```
class HardwareId {
    public UUID read() {
        Preferences pref = Preferences.systemNodeForPackage(HardwareId.class);
        String uuid = pref.get("UUID", null);
        if (uuid == null) {
            uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            pref.put("UUID", uuid);
            pref.flush();
        }
        return UUID.fromString(uuid);
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be exactly what I'm looking for. Would `systemNodeForPackage` settings be available even if the application is deleted and re-downloaded? Also, if I were to update the client application and release a new version, would the new application be able to use the same preferences as the old version? To clarify that question, on Windows all of my settings are preserved even in the case of an update because the new version reads and writes to the same registry. Would this API provide this functionality? Regardless, +1 for this answer. If the API works, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: After reading more about this API, I've answered my own questions about this API. This seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you for your answer and help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered databases to store the value.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Derby

From wikipedia "Apache Derby (previously distributed as IBM Cloudscape) is a relational database management system (RDBMS) developed by the Apache Software Foundation that can be embedded in Java programs and used for online transaction processing."

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I just read through the wikipedia page and did a quick search for "JavaDB" (the Wikipedia page says "JavaDB" comes with Java 7 and is exactly the same as Apache Derby). From what I read, it appears that Apache Derby is only for online usage. If you can provide information about implementing it locally, I would appreciate it. Also, where does the database save to?